# Google GCM not registering on some devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My application is not registering on GCM for some devices. HTC explorer , Galaxy S2 are the devices which are not registering. However LG optimus 4x hd , Galaxy s4 , samsung duos , y are the devices where it is registering with GCM. I am posting my manifest. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.suremcx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.suremcx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.suremcx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_om"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.suremcx.utils.MyApplication"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.suremcx.activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.suremcx.activity.MenuActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.suremcx.activity.CustomChatActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.suremcx.activity.TipsFragment" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.suremcx.activity.GcmBroadCastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.suremcx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.suremcx.activty.PushNotificationService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled 'activity' in `com.suremcx.activty.PushNotificationService`